# How can an android app detect a bluetooth headset without bluetooth permissions?

Tags: android, bluetooth, headset

I recently obtained a bluetooth headset, and noticed that although Google Play Music detects when it pairs, and starts showing a 'switch between phone speakers and bluetooth headset' control, its manifest (as reconstructed by AppXplore) does not list any bluetooth permissions.

Does anyone here know what API it might be using for that, which doesn't require bluetooth permissions?

Or are Google cheating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gah. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setBluetoothScoOn(boolean)

Here's hoping it also routes the microphone, which is what I'm really after..!